# Using GKE with an HTTP Proxy

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

Is it possible to run a private GKE cluster(private endpoint and nodes) behind an HTTP proxy?

GKE nodes need an internet connection to pull docker images from public repositories. The problem is, we don't want to login each GKE nodes and configure `http_proxy` environment variables and repeat this after every cluster upgrades.

Is it possible to automate setting `http_proxy` environment variable for each node or is there a better way to configure `http_proxy` on a private GKE cluster?

Comment: are you opposed to running a NAT gateway such as Cloud NAT?

Comment: alternatively, you can push all the unavailable images to a GCR

Comment: OR you can run a daemonset with root privilege to make changes to the node and add the http_proxy

Comment: All traffic must go via a forward proxy, gcr with google private access or an internal repository is an alternative but for now we decided to use DaemonSet. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DaemonSet](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/daemonset) for deploying ongoing background tasks (automate setting http_proxy) that you need to run on all or certain nodes. Example:

```
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: startup-script
  labels:
    app: startup-script
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: startup-script
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      containers:
        - name: startup-script
          image: gcr.io/basic-app-with-example/startup-script:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          env:
          - name: STARTUP_SCRIPT
            value: |
              #! /bin/bash
              list of the command that you need to execute in node
              export http_proxy='http://<host>:<port>'
```

And you could use Cloud NAT in GCP to allow your private GKE cluster to reach public repositories.

Comment: Question: Why is there an image specified? I.e. (gcr.io/basic-app-with-example/startup-script:v1.). Isn't it enough to write the bash command (i.e. `export http_proxy='http://<host>:<port>' ?

Comment: Is image gcr.io/basic-app-with-example/startup-script:v1 a public one? Unsure how you chose which image to list in 'containers'....